# PHP Regex Returning Blank Value when Using Or

Tags: php, regex

My regex returns a blank value when the second value is matched in an OR statement, I want it to ignore the first match if the second one is found

```
preg_match('/>\s+(?:<input type="submit" value="(.*?)" \/>|<p class="no">(.*?)<\/p>)\s+<\/form>/', $string, $matches);
```

If first item is matched:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    [1] => Go
)
```

If second item is matched:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p class="no">Value</p>
    [1] => 
    [2] => Value
)
```

How can I get it to return the second items value in [1] and not [2] ?

Comment: You start by not using regexes on html... There be monsters down that road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `(?:` to start the options, use `(?|` [[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)]

Comment: Wow you learn something new every day. Definitely deserves +1.